# Laravel 9: imagettftext(): Invalid font filename

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-controller

I have a Controller method like this:

```
public function singleChar($text)
{
   $font = 'SansBold.ttf';

   ...

   imagettftext($img, $size, $angle + 5, $textX + 5, $textY + 10, $shadowgbColor, $font, $text);

   ... 
 }
```

But I'm afraid that's not right because I get this error:

> imagettftext(): Invalid font filename

And I think this error occurs because I have wrongly called the font `SansBold.ttf`. So I wonder what the correct way of calling this font inside this Controller Method is? And also, where should I place the font?

**Note that** I'm using PHP v8 and also enabled GD Library by uncommenting `;extension=gd` inside `php.ini`. I'm stuck with this and would appreciate any idea or suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify the full path to the font file.

it is better to use the `public` folder to store the font (if you need to have public access to it)
or the `storage/app` folder (if you only use it inside your laravel application)

In the first case, getting the path will look like this:

```
$font = public_path('fonts/SansBold.ttf'); // your file here: public/fonts/SansBold.ttf
```

In the second case:

```
$font = storage_path('app/fonts/SansBold.ttf'); // your file here: storage/app/fonts/SansBold.ttf
```